# NTILE() in BigQuery for non-uniform buckets

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to perform RFM segmentation on the Google Merchandise Store sample dataset on BigQuery. In my SQL query, NTILE(5) divides the rows into 5 buckets based on row ordering and returns the bucket number that is assigned to each row. In this case, each bucket are of equal size. Would like to find out how to create buckets of different sizes instead. For example, bucket 1 contains the bottom 10%, bucket 2 contains the next 20% of records etc. Thank you!

```
#standard SQL    
  SELECT
      fullVisitorId,
      NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY last_order_date) AS rfm_recency,
      NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY count_order) AS rfm_frequency,
      NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY avg_amount) AS rfm_monetary
    FROM (
      SELECT
        fullVisitorId,
        MAX(date) AS last_order_date,
        COUNT(*) AS count_order,
        AVG(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)/1000000 AS avg_amount
      FROM
        `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170*`
      WHERE
        _table_suffix BETWEEN "101"
        AND "801"
        AND totals.totalTransactionRevenue IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY
        fullVisitorId )
```

Comment: can you clarify your issue  - looks like NTILE(10) does what you are looking for - at least while you use 10%, 20% etc. as an example of what you want because those are still buckets of equal size. if you can be more specific in what you need we can help better

Comment: Hi @Mikhail, sorry I was away for a week for some personal matters. For example, I would like to create 5 bins, the first bin containing 0-10%, the second 10-30%, the third 30-60%, the fourth 60-70%, and the last bin containing 70%-100%. Sorry for the confusion there, but I would l like to create bins of different sizes.

Comment: got it! see my answer then :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and `count(*)` to define your own buckets:

```
SELECT fullVisitorId,
       (CASE WHEN seqnum_r <= 0.1 * cnt THEN 1
             WHEN seqnum_r <= 0.3 * cnt THEN 2
             ELSE 3
        END) as bin_r,
       . . .               
FROM (SELECT fullVisitorId,
             MAX(date) AS last_order_date,
             COUNT(*) AS count_order,
             (AVG(totals.totalTransactionRevenue) / 1000000) AS avg_amount,
             COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(date)) as seqnum_r,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*)) as seqnum_f,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)) as seqnum_m
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170*`
      WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN "101" AND "801" AND
            totals.totalTransactionRevenue IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY fullVisitorId
     ) rfm
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and assumes your initial query works for for you, SQL UDF NON_UNIFORM_BUCKET() does the trick for you

```
#standard SQL    
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION NON_UNIFORM_BUCKET(i INT64) AS (
  CASE 
    WHEN i = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN i IN (2, 3) THEN 2
    WHEN i IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 3
    WHEN i = 7 THEN 4
    ELSE 5
  END
);
  SELECT
      fullVisitorId,
      NON_UNIFORM_BUCKET(NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY last_order_date)) AS rfm_recency,
      NON_UNIFORM_BUCKET(NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY count_order)) AS rfm_frequency,
      NON_UNIFORM_BUCKET(NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY avg_amount)) AS rfm_monetary
    FROM (
      SELECT
        fullVisitorId,
        MAX(date) AS last_order_date,
        COUNT(*) AS count_order,
        AVG(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)/1000000 AS avg_amount
      FROM
        `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170*`
      WHERE
        _table_suffix BETWEEN "101"
        AND "801"
        AND totals.totalTransactionRevenue IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY
        fullVisitorId )
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail! Didn't know I could write user defined functions like that as I'm quite new to SQL and BigQuery. Learned something new today! :)